# Send Anonymous Type (List) to View in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, anonymous-types

I'm trying to send an anonymous type to my view.

The anonymous type is constructed in the following way:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Historial()
    {
        return View(await _context.HechosLiquidador
            .Select(c => new { Store = c.StoreID, LiqDate = c.FechaLFinLiq}).Distinct()
            .AsNoTracking().OrderBy(s => s.LiqDate).ToListAsync());
    }
```

The particularity of this case is that the result of the query is a list of items. How can I pass this to the view?

Should I construct a ViewModel? If that is the case, how can I populate that view model with the result of this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a ViewModel as a solution to my problem.

ViewModel:

```
public class HistorialIndexData
{
    public string StoreName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaLFinLiq { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller we will, at first, get the items that we want to list. Next we iterate through the object that contains those items and then store them on the ViewModel to finally be used to create a new list.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Historial()
{
   List<HistorialIndexData> newHistorial = new List<HistorialIndexData>();
   var items = await _context.HechosLiquidador.Include(s => s.Stores)
              .Select(c => new { Store = c.Stores.StoreName, LiqDate = c.FechaLFinLiq })
              .Distinct()
              .AsNoTracking().OrderBy(s => s.LiqDate)
              .ToListAsync();

   foreach(var itemtolist in items)
   {
     HistorialIndexData info = new HistorialIndexData
     {
       StoreName = itemtolist.Store,
       FechaLFinLiq = itemtolist.LiqDate
     };
     newHistorial.Add(info);
   }

   return View(newHistorial);
}
```

Update the view to work with the ViewModel.

```
@model List<Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.HistorialIndexData>
```